# Button1 and then Button2 when click it will generate one "letter or character" - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, switch-statement

If the title is still a bit confusing what I really mean is that "when I click the button 1 followed by button 2 (with a bit time interval) it will generate a "letter" or "character" depending what values you coded on it it will input in textbox.

Please help I need this to complete my android application. I am having hard time dealing with this one.

My Code:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/block1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="A"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```

inside my onCreate()

```
Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block1);
Button B = (Button) findViewById(R.id.block2);
```

then setOnClickListener

```
A.setOnClickListener(this);
B.setOnClickListener(this);
```

inside my onClick() method and I did declare a global variable. `String letter;`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.block1:
             letter += "A";  
             tts.speak("A.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
             break;
        case R.id.block2:
            letter += "B";  
             tts.speak("B.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
             break;
        .
        .
        just like that..
```

Please do tell me what I am missing or what is needed to revised. Please do correct me If I'm wrong.. **That is already a working program, but as I said earlier that I want a **"one click after another"** then it will generate a single "variable/character" in the textbox.

EDITED:

[image]

Comment: we appreciate you tried but what is the issue you are currently facing ? you need to be specific about the issue

Comment: @PavneetSingh Hello good day, I added a picture :) It is just I don't know how to implement a "e.g: when you click 1st block (buttonA) then 2nd block (buttonB) it will generate a "value on textbox" **one after another** sir.

Comment: you need to initialize your `textview`  using `findViewById` and use `textview.setText(letter);` inside click listener

Comment: I already got that. :) The only left is the combination of buttons. Block1+Block2 (one after another with a time interval in every click) it will generate a "Character or variable".. Can you please help me with that one? :(

Comment: Are you wanting to trigger the "action" always after two buttons have been tapped or after a possibly longer combo?

Comment: Yees after the two buttons has been tapped it will trigger an "action". There are some others "letters" that needs a combination of four buttons. So yeah I think if I get just the two buttons I can somehow manage it.. @Tigger -Please help me with this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will write a simple answer based on what I understand of what you are asking...

I suggest you add a variable,

```
boolean aPressed = false;
```

Then in the click listener for A change the variable to true, Start a timer and then have an if statement in your B button's click listener testing if A was clicked from the variable aPressed. Afterwards stop the timer, see if the time taken meets what you want and put the text inside the text box as you wish.

I will not go into greater detail as it is unclear of what you are asking and I am surprised this hasn't been closed.

**Hope I helped,**

**-Daniel**

Comment: Hello what I really mean is that " It will trigger an action after two buttons has been tapped"

Comment: With a period in between or together?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, but for e.g: when you click the buttonA then buttonB it will trigger an action. (depending on what's the code you input)

Answer (score 0):

The following is simple logic, not exact code that will work.

```
// Replace "String" with the correct type to suit the task
private String mButOneValue = "";

private void twoClickAction(String valueOne, String valueTwo) {
    ... perform the action here using the passed fields ...    
}

// This would be your current switch statement maybe. This 
// prevents a long method with possible code duplication.
private String getValueOfClick(View v) {
    ... extract the "value" you want to track ...
    return theValueYouWorkedOut;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mButOneValue.equals("")) {
        // capture the first value you want to track.
        mButOneValue = getValueOfClick(v);

    } else {
         // first click value is known, get the second and
         // and perform the action you want.
         twoClickAction(mButOneValue, getValueOfClick(v));

         // And be sure to clear the value first value.
         mButOneValue = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello as I have to generate a letter from "A-Z" So I don't think your approach will gonna work.. https://youtu.be/wQE870a_S3k?t=1m35s This is what I'm aiming though..

Comment: After checking out what you want to make, I think a bitwise / flag system for the 6 buttons (that is values of 1,2,4,8,16,32) would be better. For example; 1 = A, (1+4) = B, (1+2) = C ... etc. The only issue is how do you "register" that letter combo as being complete or valid? Either way I suggest you delete this question and make a new one that is clearer and includes more details on what is you really want to do (and what you have tried) because your current question does not fit with your objective. For example, 2 button clicks then action but sometimes 1 (A) and sometimes 5 (Q).